# Join clause including soft-deleted rows

Tags: postgresql, go, go-pg

I am having trouble generating correct select query with joins using `go-pg` orm where one table record can be soft-deleted and other 2 cant.

DB tables:

| pipeline_instances |
| --- |
| instance_id int |
| pipeline_id int |
| event_id int |

| pipeline_triggers |
| --- |
| id int |
| pipeline_id int |
| deleted_at timestamp |

| pipeline_trigger_events |
| --- |
| event_id int |
| trigger_id int |

go-pg Models:

```
type pipelineTriggerEvent struct {
    tableName        struct{}          `pg:"pipeline_trigger_events,alias:pte"`
    Trigger          *pipelineTrigger  `pg:"rel:has-one,join_fk:id"`
    PipelineInstance *pipelineInstance `pg:"rel:has-one,join_fk:event_id"`
    *TriggerEvent
}

type pipelineTrigger struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"pipeline_triggers,alias:pt"`
    *Trigger 
}

type pipelineInstance struct {
    tableName struct{} `pg:"pipeline_pipeline_instances,alias:ppi"`
    *PipelineInstance
}
```

The query I am trying to generate:

```
SELECT 
  pte.*, trigger.*, pipeline_instance.*
FROM 
  pipeline_trigger_events AS pte 
  LEFT JOIN pipeline_triggers AS trigger ON (trigger.id = pte.trigger_id) 
  LEFT JOIN pipeline_pipeline_instances AS pipeline_instance ON pipeline_instance.event_id = pte.event_id AND trigger.pipeline_id = pipeline_instance.pipeline_id
```

The query getting generated by go-pg orm:

```
SELECT 
  pte.*, trigger.*, pipeline_instance.*
FROM 
  pipeline_trigger_events AS pte 
  LEFT JOIN pipeline_triggers AS trigger ON (trigger.id = pte.trigger_id) 
      AND trigger.deleted_at IS NULL -- this is the unwanted line.
  LEFT JOIN pipeline_pipeline_instances AS pipeline_instance ON pipeline_instance.event_id = pte.event_id AND trigger.pipeline_id = pipeline_instance.pipeline_id
```

```
var triggerevents []pipelineTriggerEvent
q := db.Model(&triggerevents).
        Column("pte.*").
        Relation("Trigger").
        Relation("PipelineInstance", func(q *orm.Query) (*orm.Query, error) {
            q = q.Join(" AND trigger.pipeline_id = pipeline_instance.pipeline_id")
            return q, nil
        })
```

Of all the 3 tables/models mentioned above, only pipeline_triggers table has `deleted_at` column that is used for soft deletion. My requirement is to include the soft deleted pipeline_triggers rows also in the result set. But `go-pg` orm is automatically adding the `trigger.deleted_at IS NULL` condition in the `join` clause. How can I remove this condition and get all rows including soft deleted ones.

I tried using [AllWithDeleted](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-pg/pg/v10@v10.10.4/orm#Query.AllWithDeleted) function but it works on the main model, which is pipeline_trigger_events (and this table does not have deleted_at column anyway) and not on `pipeline_triggers` and therefore fails with this error:
`pg: model=PipelineTriggerEvent does not support soft deletes`

Comment: Where in your code have you tried adding AllWithDeleted()? Does it work if you add it after the call to q.join? i.e. `q.join(...).AllWithDeleted()`

Comment: @kimbo Tried alter `Relation("Trigger")`, after `Relation("PipelineInstance")` and after `q.Join("...")`. They all give the same error that pipelineTriggerEvent does not have a deleted_at column

Comment: Since you know the sql you want, you can just pass that in to db.Query or db.QueryWithContext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking through the code of pg-go a bit, I don’t know if what you’re trying to do is supported. To know for sure you’d probably want to step through the code below in a debugger.

When the query is being built for the joins, it has this section:

https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/c9ee578a38d6866649072df18a3dbb36ff369747/orm/join.go#L283

```
if isSoftDelete {
        b = append(b, " AND "...)
        b = j.appendAlias(b)
        b = j.appendSoftDelete(b, q.flags)
    }
```

The line `j.appendAlias(b)` calls the `appendAlias()` function below:
https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/c9ee578a38d6866649072df18a3dbb36ff369747/orm/join.go#L200

```
func appendAlias(b []byte, j *join) []byte {
    if j.hasParent() {
        b = appendAlias(b, j.Parent)
        b = append(b, "__"...)
    }
    b = append(b, j.Rel.Field.SQLName...)
    return b
}
```

Since the joins both have a has-one parent relation, it gets added for all the tables:
https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/c9ee578a38d6866649072df18a3dbb36ff369747/orm/join.go#L153

```
func (j *join) hasParent() bool {
    if j.Parent != nil {
        switch j.Parent.Rel.Type {
        case HasOneRelation, BelongsToRelation:
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

I think what would fix this for you would be to only call `appendAlias()` for the parent relation and not the other two, but it doesn’t look like that’s supported by pg-go.

What you can do for this is just call `pg.Query()` or `pg.QueryWithContext()` and pass in the sql statement you included above.

It’s also worth mentioning that pg-go/pg is in maintenance mode so it’s unlikely they’ll ever support this. Depending on how entrenched this project is in pg-go, you might consider using [Bun](https://bun.uptrace.dev/guide/pg-migration.html) which is actively being developed.

Appendix

Here’s the `appendSoftDelete()` function that gets called in the first snippet above:

https://github.com/go-pg/pg/blob/c9ee578a38d6866649072df18a3dbb36ff369747/orm/join.go#L189

```
func (j *join) appendSoftDelete(b []byte, flags queryFlag) []byte {
    b = append(b, '.')
    b = append(b, j.JoinModel.Table().SoftDeleteField.Column...)
    if hasFlag(flags, deletedFlag) {
        b = append(b, " IS NOT NULL"...)
    } else {
        b = append(b, " IS NULL"...)
    }
    return b
}
```